# Using awk to return only certain chunks of data

Tags: regex, awk, pattern-matching

I'm not 100% certain how to phrase my question simply, so I apologize if this has been answered somewhere and I was just unable to find it.

What I have are debug logs with authentication packets in them along with a bunch of other output. I need to search through about 2 million lines of logs to find every packet that contains a certain mac address.

The packets look something like this (slightly censored):

```
-----------------[ header ]-----------------
Event:     Authd-Response (1900)
Sequence:  -54
Timestamp: 1969-12-31 19:30:00 (0)
---------------[ attributes ]---------------
Auth-Result = Auth-Accept
Service-Profile-SID = 53
Service-Profile-SID = 49
RADIUS-Access-Accept-Attr/WiMAX-Capability = 0x(numbers)
Session-Timeout = 3600
Service-Profile-SID = 4
Service-Profile-SID = 29
Chargeable-User-Identity = "(Numbers)"
User-Password = "(the MAC address I'm looking for)"
--------------------------------------------
```

However there are about 10 different possible types with different possible lengths. They all start with the header line and end with the all-dashes line.

I've had success using awk to get the code blocks themselves using this:

```
awk '/-----------------\[ header \]-----------------/,/--------------------------------------------/' filename.txt
```

But I was hoping to be able to use it to return only the packets which contain the MAC address that I need.

I've been trying to figure this out for a few days now and I'm pretty stuck. I could try and write a bash script, but I could swear that I've used awk to do something like this before...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way.

Assuming `infile` with following content (three headers with different MACs):

```
-----------------[ header ]-----------------
Event:     Authd-Response (1900)
Sequence:  -54
Timestamp: 1969-12-31 19:30:00 (0)
---------------[ attributes ]---------------
Auth-Result = Auth-Accept
Service-Profile-SID = 53
Service-Profile-SID = 49
RADIUS-Access-Accept-Attr/WiMAX-Capability = 0x(numbers)
Session-Timeout = 3600
Service-Profile-SID = 4
Service-Profile-SID = 29
Chargeable-User-Identity = "(Numbers)"
User-Password = "ab:89:67:45:23:01"
--------------------------------------------
-----------------[ header ]-----------------
Event:     Authd-Response (1900)
Sequence:  -54
Timestamp: 1969-12-31 19:30:00 (0)
---------------[ attributes ]---------------
Auth-Result = Auth-Accept
Service-Profile-SID = 53
Service-Profile-SID = 49
RADIUS-Access-Accept-Attr/WiMAX-Capability = 0x(numbers)
Session-Timeout = 3600
Service-Profile-SID = 4
Service-Profile-SID = 29
Chargeable-User-Identity = "(Numbers)"
User-Password = "01:23:45:67:89:ab"
--------------------------------------------
-----------------[ header ]-----------------
Event:     Authd-Response (1900)
Sequence:  -54
Timestamp: 1969-12-31 19:30:00 (0)
---------------[ attributes ]---------------
Auth-Result = Auth-Accept
Service-Profile-SID = 53
Service-Profile-SID = 49
RADIUS-Access-Accept-Attr/WiMAX-Capability = 0x(numbers)
Session-Timeout = 3600
Service-Profile-SID = 4
Service-Profile-SID = 29
Chargeable-User-Identity = "(Numbers)"
User-Password = "00:00:45:67:89:ab"
--------------------------------------------
```

Run following `awk` script:

```
awk -v mac="01:23:45:67:89:ab" '
    BEGIN { 
        RS = "-+\\[ header \\]-+"; 
        FS = "\n"; 
    } 
    ## Save record separator. I must do at the beginning because later the
    ## variable is reset. ¿Bug?
    FNR == 1 {
        record_sep = RT;
    }
    { 
        ## Go throught each line searching for the MAC. If found print
        ## the whole block.
        for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++ ) { 
            if ( match( $i, mac ) > 0 ) {
                print record_sep, $0;
                break;
            }
        } 
    }
' infile
```

That yields:

```
-----------------[ header ]----------------- 
Event:     Authd-Response (1900)
Sequence:  -54
Timestamp: 1969-12-31 19:30:00 (0)
---------------[ attributes ]---------------
Auth-Result = Auth-Accept
Service-Profile-SID = 53
Service-Profile-SID = 49
RADIUS-Access-Accept-Attr/WiMAX-Capability = 0x(numbers)
Session-Timeout = 3600
Service-Profile-SID = 4
Service-Profile-SID = 29
Chargeable-User-Identity = "(Numbers)"
User-Password = "01:23:45:67:89:ab"
--------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU awk):

```
awk '$0~mac{printf($0.RT)}' mac="01:23:45:67:89:ab" RS="\n[-]+\n" file
```

Where `mac` is your chosen address.

Answer (score 0):

some awks support multi-char record separators. If the '------' line is always the same length then

```
 awk 'BEGIN{ORS=RS="^---------------------$";}/macAddress/{print}' logfile
```

should work.

(Extending, of course the '----' to match the length of you true rec separator.

IHTH

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v mac=MACADDR '
     /^-----------------\[ header \]-----------------$/ { inpacket=1; found=0 }
     inpacket { packet = packet "\n" $0; if (/User-Password = / && $3 == mac) { found=1 } }
     /^--------------------------------------------$/ && found { print packet; inpacket=0 }'
```

I assumed that the quotes and parentheses in your above example are not actually part of the file format. If they are, change the first line to:

```
awk -v mac='"('MACADDR')"' '
```